# How to show action bar overflow menu support in without using ActionBarActivity android 2.x version

Tags: android, android-menu

Can anybody tell How to show action bar overflow menu support in without using ActionBarActivity android 2.x version

Thanks

Comment: What are your concerns with `ActionBarActivity`? You can use [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) if you specifically do not like `appcompat_v7`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am implemented facebook sliding in my application .I am not able to sliding action bar.In same page i want action bar over flow menu can you tell how to do

Answer (score 0):

write in your menu file
Create sample project and chk

replace THREE_VERTICAL_DOTS_IMAGE by overflow image it will work for all version/all screen

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/empty"
    android:icon="@drawable/THREE_VERTICAL_DOTS_IMAGE"
    android:orderInCategory="101"
    android:showAsAction="always">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_4"
            android:showAsAction="always|withText"
            android:title="1st menu"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_3"
            android:showAsAction="always|withText"
            android:title="2nd menu"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_mark_skip"
            android:showAsAction="always|withText"
            android:title="3rd menu"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_2"
            android:showAsAction="always|withText"
            android:title="4th menu"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/action_1"
            android:showAsAction="always|withText"
            android:title="5 menu"/>
    </menu>
</item>
```

Comment: It will not work for devices that lack a MENU button and lack an action bar.

Comment: Please feel free to explain how it can work, when the user cannot access it. If there is no MENU button, and there is no action bar, there is no means for the user to access your menu.